# Change value of first iteration input with next iteration input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

**Structure Concept:-**
Basically, i am trying to create the modal window containing input and that modal window currently fires when the input on index page get focused for that I have used data attribute to make a link between them by assigning them same attribute value.

**Javascript Concept:-**
for the modal window, I have created the modal object. and model object contains a bindModal method which takes one argument and that argument is data attribute value. after taking that value bindModal method will search dom elements containing that particular value and after the search, I iterate over them using each loop.

***Problem***
So basically I want whenever user starts typing on the model input it should get written automatically in input on the index page.

**I will appreciate you all if guys help me out to make my code more optimized and well structured and most important thing is that let me know what mistake I have done in overall work *Thanks***

**JavaScript Code**

```
   var modal = function () {
    this.toggleModal = function () {
        $('#modal').toggleClass('content--inActive').promise().done(function () {
            $('#modal__close').on('click',function(){
                $('#modal').addClass('content--inActive');
            });
        });
    }
    this.bindModal = function (bindVal) {
        var bindValue = $(document).find('[data-modal-bind = ' + bindVal + ']');
        $.each(bindValue, function (index) {
            var bind1 = $(this);
            if(index === 1) {
                var bind2 = $(this);
                $(bind1).change(function (){
                    $(bind2).val(bind1.val());
                });
            }
        });

    }
}

var open = new modal();

$('#input_search').on('click',function(){
    open.toggleModal();
    open.bindModal('input');
});
```

Comment: So basically you want to update the value in real-time?

Comment: yes i want to update the value in real time

Comment: `change` event fires on focus out. If you want real-time update, use `keypress`, or `keyup` event instead.

Comment: not woking even after chaning it to keypress

Comment: Can you please provide a plunker or fiddle with your code?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/MXj7jbsGzCDaeQkbsIAC?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do what you want:

```
var modal = function() {
  this.bindModal = function(bindVal) {
    var bindValue = $('[data-modal-bind = ' + bindVal + ']');
    bindValue.each(function(index) {
      $(this).keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        bindValue.each(function(i, e) {
          $(this).val(value);
        });
      });
    });

  }
}

$('#input_search').on('click', function() {
  var open = new modal();
  open.bindModal('input');
});
```

**Changes done:**

I cached the inputs with same binding values in `bindValue` variable, and then bound the the `keyup` event for each of them. On `keyup`, the value of the current input is get in `value`, which is then assigned to each input using the inner loop.

This makes the inputs to be in sync while typing. Hope that solves your issue.

Comment: thanks, bro it works one more thing structure which I have made is a valid structure or not( is it good way or not)

Comment: @NiteshYadav -- I won't recommend reinventing the wheel. Try to use an MVVM framework, which certainly eases the life. [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) is a well-known framework for such task.